# Why my program does not wait for animation in Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, animation, concurrency, javafx

I want my program to do something after an `PathTransition` finishes. So I created a thread to run the animation, along with join() method to let the program to wait for this thread. Here is my trial code below

```
public class JavaFXApplication6 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(new Image("File:1.JPG"));
        iv.setFitHeight(80);
        iv.setFitWidth(50);
        PathTransition pt = new PathTransition();
        pt.setNode(iv);
        pt.setCycleCount(1);
        pt.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
        pt.setPath(new Path(new MoveTo(0, 0), new LineTo(200, 200)));
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        root.getChildren().add(iv);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        Thread t = new Thread (){
            public void run(){
               pt.play();
            }
        };
        t.start();
        try {
        t.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException w){}
        System.out.println("I should be printed after the animation!");
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

However, the String printed out before the animation finishes. Why this could happen? Isn't is the deal that whatever after join() will wait for that thread to die?

If thread can't achieve this, what trick can i use to let program wait for animations, **without using** `.setOnFinished()`?

Comment: `pt.play()` schedules the animation to be run on the JavaFX application thread and returns immediately. Thus there is no point in starting a new thread for the animation. `setOnFinished()` is the right way. What is the problem with it?

Comment: @TomasMikula  I dont know. seems 'setOnFinished()' makes the program linear if there are a few animation to play one by one ......

Comment: What do you mean by "makes the program linear"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accroding to https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#play() :
`Animation#play()` (`PathTransition` inherits it) is an asynchronous call, meaning it probably goes on a new thread, not linked to the thread you started, which ends immediately after that call.

Comment: Then how to wait for that animation?

Comment: You have already answered that yourself. To execute code after the animation, you use setOnFinished(...).

Comment: @James_D is that the only way to do it？

Comment: @James_D :hello can you help me with my issue? stackoverflow.com/q/27182323/2722799

Comment: There are essentially equivalent ways, but that's effectively the only way to do it. Why do you need a different way?